# SMS not working on 4.6.2

Tags: sms

Updated to version 2 of the extension.  Messages not being delivered.  Manually executed.  Will clickatell extension work on 4.6.2?
Success is reported but message never sent.  Here is error from the log:

May 19 04:24:40  [info] $Fatal Error Details = Array
(
    [message] => Unknown extension: org.civicoop.smsapi
    [code] => 
    [exception] => CRM_Extension_Exception_MissingException Object
        (
            [errorData:CRM_Core_Exception:private] => Array
                (
                    [error_code] => 0
                )

```
        [cause:protected] => 
        [_trace:PEAR_Exception:private] => 
        [message:protected] => Unknown extension: org.civicoop.smsapi
        [string:Exception:private] => 
        [code:protected] => 0
        [file:protected] => /home/depot/public_html/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Extension/Container/Collection.php
        [line:protected] => 143
        [trace:Exception:private] => Array
            (
```

Comment: SMS reports success but is not sent.  Here it the error from the log files

Comment: Could you clarify your question? What do you mean by version 2 and what extension? And what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

have you installed [this extension](https://civicrm.org/extensions/sms-api)

Could you download and install it manually and report if it works? Its configuration file hasn't been updated to say it's compatible with 4.6, but we will do it once you confirm if works well.

Comment: Was able to install the extension but it doesn't come up as a selection when trying to add an SMSProvider.

Comment: Anymore ideas?  Where do I look for the log files?  I have tried turning them on, but can't find them.

Comment: It shouldn't add a new SMSProvider, but should be the missing bit to get the one you tried first working

Comment: Ok.  It is installed but my messages still are not being delivered.

Comment: Error message is CRM_Core_Error::fatal("Provider not known or not provided.

Comment: Then it's another problem is seems. Can you close this question and create a new one with the complete log of the error?

Comment: Got that corrected with a path fix.  Now no errors, but still not working.